# angular-auth0 issue: Unknown provider: authProvider <- auth

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I am replacing Lock 9 for Lock 10 on my app to be able to add custom options to the signup widget (additional email and password confirmation). To make the transition smooth I am using this library https://github.com/auth0/angular-auth0, as suggested by Ryan Chenkie on this auth0 forum: https://auth0.com/forum/t/is-lock-10-incompatible-with-angular/3297/9 (last post).

According to the library docs, after implementing the scripts and registering the module `auth0.auth0` I should have access to `auth0Provider` in my config block and be able to use it to config the `init` method. This is the implementation on the docs (you may visit the link as well):

```
bower install angular-auth0

<script src="bower_components/auth0.js/build/auth0.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-auth0/build/angular-auth0.js"></script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['auth0.auth0']);

app.config(function(auth0Provider) {
  auth0Provider.init({
   clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
   domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN
  });
});
```

This should allow me to use `auth` in my controllers or runblock in such fashion:

```
app.run(function(auth) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.auth = auth;
});
```

However, when I load the app I get this error message: `Unknown provider: authProvider <- auth`.

Additionally, the file `bower_components/angular-auth0/build/angular-auth0.js` doesn't have an `auth0Provider` but an `angularAuth0Provider`, which I can inject in the config block but doesn't give me access to `auth`, generating the same `Unknown provider: authProvider <- auth` error.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if the implementation I am trying is not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to use `angularAuth0` as opposed to `auth` but I am not sure these objects are equivalent anyway. I imagined the app should simply work like before without further configuration, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The latest angular package `angularAuth0` is a departure from the original in that it's just a thin wrapper around the `auth0.js` library instead of a more robust client. `auth` no longer exists and is instead replaced by `angularAuth0` which has different functionality altogether. Also, take a look at `angular-jwt` as much of the `isAuthenticated` type functionality has moved over to it: https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt

This upgrade is a complete departure from previous integrations :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was a conflict in the libraries we are using. We fixed it. If you want to read more about the issue, please find my comments and Ryan Chenkie's on this auth0 forum: https://auth0.com/forum/t/is-lock-10-incompatible-with-angular/3297/11

Comment: Thanks - from a Single Page App perspective and using custom login/signup screens Auth0 is a mess.

Comment: Using the API directly instead of the lock widget worked just fine for us. The implementation is a bit more involved but just as efficient.